# Horizontal ggplot - how to position data label inside bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to position my data label inside the ggplot horizontal bar as the label gets cut off when placed at end of the bar. I have tried various different methods such as adjusting `hjust` position but the label disappears under the bar, I have even tried to increase x axis using `xlim`/ `scale_x_continuous` to allow the label to be fully viewed but so far keep failing.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

mydf <- data.frame( Category = c("Approved transactions"),
                    Nov_21=c(11028),
                    Dec_21=c(31455),
                    Jan_22=c(44480))

mydf %>%
  gather(Month, Total, -Category) %>%
  mutate(Month = reorder(Month, row_number())) %>%
  mutate(Category = reorder(Category, row_number())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Total, fill = Month, group = Category)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Total), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust= 0.25) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width=0.5, fill="light blue") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Approved Counter Transactions", subtitle = "3 Month View", legend=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: It is important to first "draw" bars `geom_bar` first and later add text `geom_text`. The order is important. Answer #2 is visually better.

Comment: exactly what Bloxx is saying, ggplot2 "layers" each geom on the previous geom. If done incorrectly geoms can obscure or cut-off each other, making @Rfanatic answer better in this case and in general when working with ggplot2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can enter the counts inside the bar plots

Sample code:

```
mydf %>%
  gather(Month, Total, -Category) %>%
  mutate(Month = reorder(Month, row_number())) %>%
  mutate(Category = reorder(Category, row_number())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Total, fill = Month, group = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width=0.5, fill="light blue") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Total),position = position_dodge(width = .4),hjust=1.3, size = 10)+
  labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Approved Counter Transactions", subtitle = "3 Month View", legend=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

Plot:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `hjust= -0.25` and add  `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = c(0, 50000))`
This is the code

```
mydf %>%
gather(Month, Total, -Category) %>%
mutate(Month = reorder(Month, row_number())) %>%
mutate(Category = reorder(Category, row_number())) %>%
ggplot(aes(Month, Total, fill = Month, group = Category)) +
geom_text(aes(label=Total), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust= -0.25) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width=0.5, fill="light blue") +
coord_flip() +
labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Approved Counter Transactions", subtitle = "3 Month View", legend=FALSE) +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
      legend.position = "none") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = c(0, 50000))
```

Comment: Thank you @Pavlo - the `scale_y_continuous` advice helps me solve an issue with another piece of code also.